# Nothing was returned from render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, render

I have this error:

> Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null.

My code :

```
export default class Header_page extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Header>
        <Left>
          <Button transparent>
            <Icon name='ios-menu' />
          </Button>
        </Left>
        <Body>
          <Title>{this.props.title}</Title>
        </Body>
        <Right>
          <View>
            {this.props.buttonRight}
          </View>
        </Right>
      </Header>
    );
  }
}

Header_page.propTypes = {
  title: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  buttonRight: PropTypes.func,
}
```

I don't understand what wrong
thanks

Answer (score 2):

Seems like `this.props.buttonRight` is declared as a function but you are not calling it, you should call it in your `render()` like so `this.props.buttonRight()`. Make sure `this.props.buttonRight()` returns some JSX or null

**Edit**

A little note: when passing a function which returns some component, I'd recommend you call it `renderSomething`, for example `renderButton`. If you pass a Component instead, call it `something` or `button`